Binding Custom Data To Textbox Headers
I am trying to make a custom header template in which I can show errors in addition to the name of the textbox. For some reason this line of code in the header template never seems to work:
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Errors, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Green" />

It always shows as blank.
But this near identical code which isn't in the header template does work:
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Supplier.Errors, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Green" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" />

This is what my program currently looks like when i make it give an error:

I want the green text at the bottom "Name should be longer..." to display next to the "Errors: " at the top in the header template of the textbox.
Also in the future I would like to make a sort of generic version of this that I could attach to all of my textboxes so they can all display error messages in their headers using a style or template from a resource dictionary.
Ie something like this:
<Style TargetType="TextBox"  x:Key="ValidatedTextBox">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Errors, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

My current xaml code for what is shown in the image:
<TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" Header="Name" PlaceholderText="Enter Name" PlaceholderForeground="Gray"  IsColorFontEnabled="True" Text="{x:Bind Supplier.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <TextBox.HeaderTemplate >
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Supplier">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
                <TextBlock>Errors: </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Errors, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Green" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
</TextBox>


<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ValidatedTextBox}" Header="Ciao" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<TextBlock Text="Name Errors: " Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" />
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Supplier.Errors, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Green" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" />
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Supplier.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Green" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" />
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"/>



You need to bind the Supplier to the Header.
<TextBox Header="{x:Bind Supplier.Errors, Mode=OneWay}" .../>


Thx for that, that solved my issue. However I realized with some experimentation that the "Errors" field contains all the errors for all the issues so many idea of putting it in the header doesn't make sense anyway. Instead I will just have a textblock at the bottom with the list of errors.
Apparently in the future version of the Windows SDK they are going to add proper Validation support. https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/7388

You need to setup the DataContext of the TextBox or Its parent.
<StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel">
    <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" PlaceholderText="Enter Name" PlaceholderForeground="Gray"  IsColorFontEnabled="True" Text="DDD">
        <TextBox.HeaderTemplate >
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:BlankWindow1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyName}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>

Code behind
public sealed partial class BlankWindow1 : Window
{
    public BlankWindow1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        MyName = "XP";

        MyStackPanel.DataContext = this;
        //NameTextBox.DataContext = this;
    }
}

Result

Edit:
From my view, HeaderTemplate is almost special and x:DataType cannot function properly. I would prefer this.
<TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox1" PlaceholderText="Enter Name" PlaceholderForeground="Gray"  IsColorFontEnabled="True" Text="DDD">
    <TextBox.HeaderTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyName}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TextBox.HeaderTemplate>
</TextBox>

